# Javascript try-catch semantics (call stack in nodejs repl)

Tags: javascript, node.js, try-catch, read-eval-print-loop

I'm somewhat new to javascript, but I wanted to try to understand how stack-tracing works in nodejs.  I was a little lazy to look at the source code, so I just consulted the language reference https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-catchclauseevaluation and tried to see what works.  So, here is the mystery: in the repl I get some odd results when catching and throwing.

When I run:

```
try { throw Error('foo'); } catch (e) { throw e; }
```

I get as output:

```
Error: foo
```

But when I run:

```
try { throw Error('foo'); } catch (e) { console.log(e); throw e; }
```

I get as output:

```
Error: foo
at repl:1:13
at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:240:29)
at bound (domain.js:301:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:468:10)
at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
Error: foo
at repl:1:13
at ContextifyScript.Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:50:33)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:240:29)
at bound (domain.js:301:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:468:10)
at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:282:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:631:8)
```

It seems as though calling `console.log(e)` causes the error object to trace the **execution context stack** (I hope I'm using this term correctly), but if it passes through to the repl without the `context.log(e)` it only knows about its error message.

I've tried different permutations of this and also nesting in different lexical contexts (functions and another try-catch block), and they all seem to give this "funny" behavior.  Also, when executing these as scripts I always get an expected error message and stack-trace, so I'm led to believe that the implementation of the repl is at fault here.  However, before diving into the source, I wanted to probe some experts to see if there is some good reason for this behavior, or if it is just a stupid corner case that I've come up with.

Comment: the one without stack can also be reproduced by simply `throw new Error('foo')`

Comment: also `let e = new Error(); throw e;` (while `let ee = new Error(); console.log(ee) throw ee;` contains stack, you don't even need the `throw`), and after that I can check `e.stack` and `ee.stack`, which contains different value

Comment: so currently I can only conclude that I don't think this is related to `try/catch`.

Comment: it seems like standard doesn't require a stack trace, though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/stack

Comment: Interesting.  I was wondering why there was no reference to the trace in the Error constructor in the standard...  I guess I should have checked mdn first.  I was thinking that maybe the error's were holding a pointer to the local execution context, and when the error is "noticed" by the repl it gets traced, but if it just "passes through" then the context is lost somehow (or traced at the point it is output, at which point there is no context, or something...)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if it's kosher to answer my own question, but I dug into the nodejs source and found out what the deal is.  I tracked it down to `repl.js: line 404`.  Here there is a call to `script.runInThisContext`.  At this point, the line `throw new Error()` "escapes" the repl and ends up getting caught a few lines below.  Here, there is check for `process.domain`, which apparently succeeds in the repl, but not in a script context.  This then emits a domain error, which doesn't do much.  If you go to `self._domain.on('error',...` you will see that all the stack tracing stuff is taken care of here.

I actually added a line `self._domain.emit('error'...` to the source right before the `process.domain.emit('error',...` call, and it then printed out a nice stack trace for me, so I'll write the guys over at nodejs and see if it is something they would like to fix.  There may be a very good reason not to do so, I didn't look into it in that great of detail.

At this point I'm reminded of a scene from *Burn after Reading.*  Watch it if you have a dry sense of humor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46h7oP9eiBk